# Getting error while saving sheet name in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to rename sheet name in excel.
Getting any error
"InvalidWorksheetName: Excel worksheet name 'AK_PC_StatusChange_04202022_Weekly' must be <= 31 chars."

Here is my code

```
writer=pd.Excelwriter('KA_Sheet' + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="KA_CP_StatusChange_0102022_Weekly")

writer.save()
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: I don't see how any answer can tell you more than the error message itself already does.

Comment: Looking for possibility ways . if the sheet name has more than 31+ char. what is the next action item , can we save that in another way or not

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory: Sheetnames must be less or equal to 31 characters. ""KA_CP_StatusChange_0102022_Weekly" is 33 characters and thus too long... Change the name and it should work. Eg.:

```
writer = pd.Excelwriter('KA_Sheet' + '.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="KA_CP_StatusChange_0102022_Wkly")
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for  your suggestion, But is there any another way to get name if it is more than 31+ char

Comment: @Karthic No. 31 characters is an Excel limit. The sheet name cannot be longer.